# Socket, how to find local address when binded with INADDR_ANY

Tags: c, sockets, server, ftp

I'm recoding a simple ftp server and I'm stuck of the implemetation of the PASV command.

In fact, when the client send a PASV command, I have to create a new server socket and send back the infos (address and port) to the client so that he can connect to it to create the data connection.

What I do step by step is:

1. Create a server socket with INADDR_ANY and random port (port 0)
2. listen() with this socket
3. getsockname() this socket to get it's infos
4. send back the infos to the client on the command connection
5. the accept() is done later, when the user need to use the data con

(Is that the right way to do it ?)

The thing is, the server socket that I create on the server side is binded with INADDR_ANY so getsockname() on it always return 0.0.0.0 (cause it is binded to virtually all the ips off the system).

Is that case, what address should I send back to the client and how to find it ?

How real ftp servers handle this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You know which local interface the current FTP connection is using. Bind to *that* interface (with a random port).

Comment: Binding to `INADDR_ANY` as you do now should work.  It would be cleaner, however, to bind only to the address the client is using.  I think you can get that by using `getsockname()` on the *connected* socket (for the command connection) instead of on the listening socket.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How do I know on which interface my current FTP connection is using ?

Comment: @JohnBollinger So I here I just getsockname the command connection socket and save the addr and bind to that with my data connection socket ? Those address will always be the same ?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: "*when the client attempts to establish the data connection, it will try to connect to the same machine with which it has already established the command connection*" - per the FTP spec, the client is *supposed* to connect to whatever IP the server says, which can be any IP the server wants, even one for another machine if it so chooses. In reality, FTP clients usually have an option to ignore the server's stated IP and just use the already-connected IP, which *usually* is fine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you are quite right.  thank you for that correction (previous comment deleted).  Theo: that does not change the fact that the IP address with which the client has established the command connection -- which should be obtainable from the connected socket -- is demonstrably an address reachable to it, modulo NAT.  If the server has to determine contextually what address to specify to the client (as opposed to being explicitly configured with that data) then I see no better address to choose.

Answer (score 1):

> What I do step by step is:
>
> 1. Create a server socket with INADDR_ANY and random port (port 0)
> 2. listen() with this socket
> 3. getsockname() this socket to get it's infos
> 4. send back the infos to the client on the command connection
> 5. the accept() is done later, when the user need to use the data con
>
> (Is that the right way to do it ?)

In general, yes, however steps #1 and #3 tend to be more complicated than that.

For one thing, `getsockname()` cannot get the true IP until the socket is actually connected to someone (which, in this case, means you would have to call `getsockname()` on the socket returned by `accept()`, not on the socket that you call `accept()` on).  So, when binding to `INADDR_ANY`, you should just report the IP of the interface that the command socket is connected to.  In which case, it is better to just bind the listening socket to only that interface directly and not to `INAADDR_ANY` at all.

For another thing, even if the server machine only has 1 interface installed, if the server is behind a NAT router, and the client is outside the NAT, then you would have to report the router's public IP instead of your server's listening IP.  You would have to know the router's public IP ahead of time, either by storing it in your app's configuration, or by dynamically querying the router itself via uPNP, or by querying an outside service like `http://iplookup.flashfxp.com/`.  Unless the router is FTP-aware (some are) and is smart enough to replace the reported IP for you when passing through the router, in which case you do have to report your listening IP instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `getsockname()` on the command socket. That gives you the IP address the client used to connect to you. It can be different for each client on a multi-homed host. If you're behind a NAT device you should use its public IP address, which you will have to obtain via configuration.